# About the width of the distribution of the kinetic energy in a gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, statistics

In [this](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/AlexanderSchekochihin/A1/2014/A1LectureNotes.pdf) lecture about statistical mechanics, page $10$, the author said that the kinetic energy $E$ of a gas can be viewed as a random variable (because it is a sum of squared velocities, which themselves are random variables), and that its probability distribution is very sharp around its mean $U=\langle E \rangle$.

[image]

He said about the above distribution,

> The distribution of the system's total energy $E$ is very sharply peaked around its mean $U=\langle E\rangle$: **the width of this peak is** $∼ΔE_{rms}/U$,

where $\Delta E _{rms}=\langle (E-\textrm {U})^{2} \rangle ^{1/2}=\sigma$.

What justifies the author's claim that the width of the distribution of $E$ can be approximated by $ΔE_{rms}/U$?

Comment: That would be for a volume of gas in contact with a heat reservoir of a certain temperature. One can calculate the probability of energy fluctuations of the subsystem from changes in entropy.

Comment: It should be emphasized that what is plotted here is the probability of finding a particular *mean particle energy*. The distribution of the individual particle energies is wide.

Comment: that is not even a function, it is multivalued at some parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim follow from central limit theorem. If you consider your energy per particle $E/N$ to be defined as $$\frac{E}{N} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \frac{mv_i^2}{2} $$
then using the central limit theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) you will find that the width of the peak of the distribution of $P(E/N )$ distribution is then $\approx 1/\sqrt{N}$.

Note the supplemental factor $1/N$ used in my formula. This would be the correct way of expressing that the distribution of energy is very peaked.

Now in your lectures, then instead compared the root-mean-square of the distribution of $E$ to its average $U$, in this case the width of your distribution should be $\Delta E _\text{rms}$. As the ratio of $\Delta E _\text{rms} / U \simeq 1/\sqrt{N}$ is very small when you effectively draw your distribution, you will get a very peaked distribution. So the claim in your lecture notes should be that the aspect ratio of your distribution is indeed $\Delta E _\text{rms} / U $, not that the width of the distribution is this ratio.